# How can I query my db for params by "and" instead of "or"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have habtm relation between products and colors. When I preform a query on products that are "red" and "black" I want it to return product that have "red" AND "black" associations not "red" OR "black"

This is my scope for this query:

```
scope :items_design_filter_color, -> (colors) { joins(:colors).where('colors.id' => colors.to_i) unless colors.nil? }
```

colors params

```
params[:colors] = ["1", "2"]
```

colors table is just id and name columns

Calling my scopes:

@products =

```
Kaminari.paginate_array(ItemsDesign.items_design_by_category(@category.subtree_ids)
                                        .items_design_filter_color(params[:colors])
                                        .items_design_filter_sort(sort)
                                        .items_design_filter_editors_pick(params[:editors_pick])
                                        .items_design_filter_sold_out(params[:sold_out])
                                        .items_design_filter_style(params[:style])
                                        .items_design_filter_store(params[:store])
                                        .items_design_filter_price(params[:low_end], params[:high_end]))
    .page(params[:page]).per(48)
```

this is my attempt at using one of the answers bellows method within my scope:

```
scope :items_design_by_category, -> (category) { joins(:items_categories).where('items_categories.id' => category) }
  scope :items_design_filter_color, -> (colors) { joins(:colors).where(colors: {id: colors}).each.select do |item|
                                                    (item.colors.map(&:id) & colors).size == colors.size
                                                  end unless colors.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_style, -> (styles) { where('items_style_id' => styles) unless styles.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_store, -> (stores) { where('store_id' => stores) unless stores.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_editors_pick, -> (editors_pick) { where('editors_pick' => TRUE) unless editors_pick.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_sold_out, -> (sold_out) { where('sold_out' => 'n') unless sold_out.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_price, -> (lowend, highend) { where('price_as_decimal' => lowend..highend) unless lowend.nil? }
  scope :items_design_filter_sort, -> (sort) { order(sort) unless sort.nil? }
```

Comment: Please show us how you do the or? By default (chaining where statements) only does AND.

Comment: That scope is doing "or" by default. Currently when this query runs with multiple colors "red", "black" it will return products that are "red" and products that are "black" I want it to return products that have "red" and "black" associated with them. Leaving out products that have only "red" or only "black" associated with them. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Mmmmm weird, that would only work if `colors` (your parameter) is an array (which would translate to an `IN` sql-operator, and thus an implicit OR), but you do an explicit call `to_i` which would fail on an array. But I understand your problem now. Is the amount of colors fixed, e.g. always two?

Comment: No it could be 1-n. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, well I ended up getting this way based on the someones answer that was deleted. If they want to come and put the answer back I will give them credit. In the meantime this solved my problem.

```
scope :items_design_filter_color, -> (colors) { color_ids = colors.map(&:to_i) unless colors.nil?
                                                includes(:colors).where(colors: {id: color_ids}).select do |item|
                                                  (item.colors.map(&:id) & color_ids).size == color_ids.size
                                                end unless colors.nil? }
```